# Question about lines connecting jobs in graphic representation of GitLab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Here is a screenshot showing part of my pipeline (censored):

[image]

It might be a stupid question, but why sometimes lines that are connecting the jobs are nice, like that:

[image]

and sometimes they are all tangled up, like here:

[image]

What does it depend on? All jobs in the stage "B" on the right have defined:

```yaml
needs:
  - A1
```

so why job A1 is connected with B1, B2 and B3 but A2 is connected only with B1? What can I do to "untangle" those lines? That is, how to make A2 connected with nothing on the right side, or with everything - not only with B1.

Here is .gitlab-ci.yml (censored/anonymised)

```yaml
stages:
  - A
  - B

A1:
  stage: A
  script:
    - something
  cache:
    paths:
      - some_cache
    policy: pull
  needs:
    - some_job_from_previous_stage_not_shown_here

A2:
  stage: A
  script:
    - something
  cache:
    paths:
      - some_cache
    policy: pull
  needs:
    - some_previous_job
  allow_failure: true

B1:
  stage: B
  script:
    - something
  cache:
    paths:
      - some_cache
    policy: pull
  needs:
    - A1

B2:
  stage: B
  script:
    - something
  cache:
    paths:
      - some_cache
    policy: pull
  needs:
    - A1

B3:
  stage: B
  script:
    - something
  cache:
    paths:
      - some_cache
    policy: pull
  needs:
    - A1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently as intended. GitLab have an Epic to resolve this, which you can follow here, along with the associated issues:

- https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/4509
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/254974

Comment: Thanks. That explains this. But why A2 is only connected with B1, and not with B2 and B3? Or it is connected or just looks like it isnt, hmm. Or it is a bug and the lines does not mean anything 

Comment: I would just say it looks tangled but it's meant to be connected, but shouldn't affect the pipeline anyhow, just the aesthetics of it